# edge web driver cant open whatsapp web

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, whatsapp

im trying this code to open web.whatsapp.comm on my edge driver

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir= .......");
options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;
EdgeDriverService driverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var driver = new EdgeDriver(driverService, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

it load normaly first time and i log in my whatsapp account by scanning QR-code, and it work normal.
second time, i close program and run again and it shoud login directly becuse i save profile by option argument.
but in secend time web page does not load and stock on loading page.
[image]
im using edge browser version 103.0.1264.44 and driver version 103.0.1264.44

Comment: Is there any error showing when you run the code? I tested with the same code and found no such connection issue. Do you have the same login problem in a normal Edge session (without automation)? You can try to clear browser cookies, scan the QR code again and see whether this happens again.

Comment: no such problem with the normal edge.
when I clear data of automated edge, it work fine just for first time